# ChatZilla connection refused

Tags: 15.04, firefox, firewall, irc

I am new to ChatZilla and IRC. I am trying to connect to Moznet and I am getting this error:

> `[INFO] Attempting to connect to “moznet”.  Use /cancel to abort.`
>     `[INFO] Connecting to irc://moznet/ (irc://irc.mozilla.org/)… [Cancel]`
>     `[ERROR] Connection to irc://moznet/ (irc://irc.mozilla.org/) refused. >[Help] Reconnecting in 15 seconds. [Cancel]`
>     `[INFO] Connecting to irc://moznet/ (ircs://irc.mozilla.org:6697/)… >[Cancel]`
>     `[ERROR] Connection to irc://moznet/ (ircs://irc.mozilla.org:6697/) >refused. [Help] Reconnecting in 15 seconds. [Cancel]`
>     `[INFO] Connecting to irc://moznet/ (irc://irc.mozilla.org/)… [Cancel]`
>     `[ERROR] Connection to irc://moznet/ (irc://irc.mozilla.org/) refused. >[Help] Reconnecting in 15 seconds. [Cancel]`

I read the FAQs which said that firewall may be blocking TCP port 6667 outgoing. I followed this link: [IRC service and UFW firewall rules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252021/irc-service-and-ufw-firewall-rules) and ran the following in Terminal:

> `sudo ufw allow out 6660:7000/tcp`

This gave output as:

> `Rules updated`
>   `Rules updated (v6)`

But I am still not able to connect to Moznet. I am working on Ubuntu 15.04 and ChatZilla version 0.9.92.

Comment: Can you disable ufw completely and check once. Just to be sure its not a firewall issue.

`sudo ufw disable`

Comment: @Nisheet I ran the command you told, and restarted the system. The Chatzilla still fails to connect to moznet and it gives the same error as above.